How to pipe on a condition in Fish?
See previous question, How to pipe on a condition in Bash. I'm interested in the same construct for Fish, i.e. shorthand for:
set check 0
if test $check = 1
    printf "foo\nbar\nbaz\n" | string match --regex ^f
else
    printf "foo\nbar\nbaz\n" | string match --regex ^b
end


This can be done via:
set check 0
printf "foo\nbar\nbaz\n" | if test $check = 1
    cat | string match --regex ^f
else
    cat | string match --regex ^b
end

Or, if you need to pipe stdin to a variable:
set check 0
printf "foo\nbar\nbaz\n" | begin
  read --local --null input
  if test $check = 1
      string match --regex ^f $input
  else
      string match --regex ^b $input
  end
end

